# Terminal Block Power Supply

Tags: power

I am beginning to build a "control centre" to deal with various elements of my vivarium.

My largest desire is to be able to control the heat source, so I was wondering if there is a terminal block that can handle 30W (unknown amperage as not at home). This would also be used to power an LED strip, which requires very low wattage and amperage.

Is there a correct way to go about this or is a terminal block with the correct resistor setup going to be safe?

Comment: [Relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use [relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay)s for this job. How many elements will use i don't know but you can use a module like [this](http://yourduino.com/sunshop2/images/products/large_201_Relay-4ch-opto-1.jpg). Relays are very simple to use and effective for you.

**Update from response to comment:**

You can use a thermo sensor like this for getting temperature (sorry for the picture quality :) )

[Sample here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing?view=all)

[image: thermostat sensor]

Comment: Ok..  But I am wanting to turn on the heat source if temp >X.   Using a replay, would it be possible to do something like this ( having it connected to the RPi?)

Comment: updated reply @SaucedApples

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at very sensitive thermometers but I am not seeing any suitable relays online also.  Obviously need to cope with 30W and I will confirm the amperage in the next hour or so when home.

Comment: improved the image and added example